# Distinguish between distributions

Tags: r, distributions, data-visualization, distribution-identification

I have the following data frame and want to know what distribution is consistent with it.

```
df <- c(63.66198,66.84508,56.65916,111.40846,92.30987,40.10705,63.66198,82.76057, 
    120.95776,80.53240,77.98592,54.11268,92.30987,60.47888,47.74648,78.94085,
    81.48733,78.30423,81.48733,79.57747,57.29578,41.06198,43.92676,54.11268,
    89.12677,44.24507,31.19437,52.83944,41.06198,124.14086,102.17747,57.29578,
    56.65916,58.56902,79.57747,44.24507,40.74367,75.43944,61.75212,52.52113,
    63.66198,61.43381,57.29578,57.29578,56.34085,57.93240,44.24507,65.25353,
    51.56620,35.01409,58.88733,59.20564,30.55775,93.90142,38.83381,82.76057,
    90.71832,95.49297,56.02254,93.90142,66.84508,50.92958,94.21973,49.01972,
    62.38874,78.94085,112.04508,77.98592,36.60564,47.74648,87.53522,51.24789,
    35.01409,34.69578,44.56338,48.38310,54.11268,65.57184,40.74367,73.21127,
    62.07043,72.89296,60.16057,91.99156,47.10986,44.24507,38.19719,63.34367,
    57.29578,63.34367,50.92958,50.29296,70.02817,38.19719,50.29296,50.29296,
    106.63381,62.38874,101.85916,50.61127,41.38029,111.40846,35.96902,46.47324,
    62.70705,63.66198,57.29578,36.60564,47.74648,60.47888,72.25634,66.84508,
    63.34367,50.92958,47.74648,117.77466,153.10706,130.82536,57.61409,47.74648,
    92.30987,35.01409,87.21691,46.79155,42.97183,74.80282,76.39437,87.53522,
    30.87606,43.60845,73.21127,54.74930,34.69578)
```

For that i used the function `descdist` (from the package `fitdistrplus`) to determine the consistent distributions with the skewness and kurtosis of my data.

```
require(fitdistrplus)
plotdist(df, histo = T, demp = T)
descdist(df, boot = 1000)
```

[image]

Then i adjusted the equations, and plotted the results with `qqPlot` from `car` package. But as you can see all distributions were consistent with the data.

How can i distinguish them (if that even possible)? Is there other methods to be used or am i missing something?

```
require(FAdist)
require(car)
b.df <- fitdist(df/1000, "beta")
w.df <- fitdist(df, "weibull")
w3.df <- fitdist(df, dweibull3, start = list(shape = 2.89320,
                                             scale = 72.21844,
                                             thres = 30.55))
g.df <- fitdist(df, "gamma")
g3.df <- fitdist(df, dgamma3, start = list(shape = 2,
                                           scale = 11,
                                           thres = 30.55))
ln.df <- fitdist(df, "lnorm")
ln3.df <- fitdist(df, dlnorm3, start = list(shape = 4.1059030,
                                            scale = 0.3403977,
                                            thres = 29))
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
qqPlot(df, distribution = "beta",
   shape1 = b.df$estimate[[1]], shape2 = b.df$estimate[[2]])

qqPlot(df, distribution = "weibull3",
       shape = w3.df$estimate[[1]], scale = w3.df$estimate[[2]], 
       thres = w3.df$estimate[[3]])

qqPlot(df, distribution = "gamma3",
       shape = g3.df$estimate[[1]], scale = g3.df$estimate[[2]],
       thres = g3.df$estimate[[3]])

qqPlot(df, distribution = "lnorm3",
       shape = ln3.df$estimate[[1]], scale = ln3.df$estimate[[2]], 
       thres = ln3.df$estimate[[3]])
```

[image]

Comment: You could try with L-moments, could be more robust

Comment: Why do you need to know what distribution fits?  It isn't very likely that real data come perfectly from any 'named' distribution. What are these data?  What are they measurements of? The beta distribution has upper & lower bounds, whereas gamma and the log normal are bounded from below at 0. Do those constraints apply to your data?